# How to get image from url using meteor / javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, filepicker

I am newbie user of meteor. I  am using file picker apis , i can easily upload my files to there server and they give me a unique url in return . When it comes to again fetch that file its creating a problem to me .

You can tell me how to get back file using that url by using filepicker api . You can tell me how to use that url and get image , by using meteor 
When i upload a picture to filepicker.io they return me a json object like following

```
[{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/kIrtNvQRta7GxlFVfiP2","filename":"brazil.jpg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":2660,"key":"ZML3OjrFTVyV4waBzRIT_brazil.jpg","isWriteable":true}]
```

So how to get the image on meteor?
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal image source should work:

```
<template name="image">
    <img src="{{img}}"/>
</template>
```

and your javascript to give it the url

```
Template.image.img = function() {
    var yourfilepickerjson = [{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/kIrtNvQRta7GxlFVfiP2","filename":"brazil.jpg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":2660,"key":"ZML3OjrFTVyV4waBzRIT_brazil.jpg","isWriteable":true}]

    return yourfilepickerjson[0] && yourfilepickerjson[0].url;
}
```

You could pass the filepickerjson via `Session` object so that its reflected reactively as soon as you get it

Comment: it just show the repective images... i need to show the images once uploaded dynamically.@Akshat

Comment: Yes you can retreive `yourfilepickerson` from a `Session.get("yourvariablename")`. As soon as you set the value with `Session.set("yourvariablename", <jsonresult>)` it should update automatically.